# How to reuse workspaces between branches with multibranch pipeline on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I've set up multibranch pipeline to track my repo and automatically build and test for all merge requests. It works wonders, however, I noticed that Jenkins creates a new workspace for each new branch. It is a pretty big project with a heavy build process and a lot of non-tracked cache files, that mostly stay valid from one version to another - so if instead of a fresh git checkout it would re-use previous workspace, it would build much faster (and also not use up so much hard drive space).

How can I configure it to re-use the same workspace for different branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching the issue, I found out that this is not something I can do with multibranch pipeline, so I switched to using the regular pipeline project. Now every build uses one of the available workspaces, so they end up re-using previous workspaces and the same cache files that really speed up the build.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins for MultiBranch projects by default uses isolated workspaces for every branch.
Jobs within the same branch use the same workspace.

A possible solution for you is to use **ws(path)** inside a pipeline.

```
node("agent_name") {
    ws(workspacePath) {
        echo '...'      
        // ..
    }
}
```